# Strange characters in output using boost::filesystem library

Tags: c++, boost, command-line-interface, ncurses, boost-filesystem

I'm using boost::filesystem to make a list of files of specified location from argv[1]. Here is the code I'm using to do it:

```
for(auto&& x : directory_iterator(dir))
{
    wprintw(win1, "%s\n", x.path().filename().string());
    wrefresh(win1);
}
```

But instead a list of files the output is

```
**^P^_^G~] ^?**
```

or

```
**0 ^]  ^?**
```

or other random characters like that.
What's the problem?

Comment: I'm trying, but I can't guess how to replace the `x.path().filename().string()` to make it work.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgive about this way. It compiles, but the problem is still here =)

Comment: Okay, now try to give it a c_string like so: `beg->path().filename().string().c_str()`

Comment: Yeah, now it works correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wprintw` is similar to `printf` for printing, it accepts a format string, followed by arguments for that format string. Methods like these are not type safe, which is why the code compiles in the first place. What it needs is a character array, and a `std::string` can not be directly used as such. Instead, we should use the `c_str()` member function to obtain one:

```
wprintw(win1, "%s\n", x.path().filename().string().c_str());
```